# For FAA currency purposes, must flight time be in an N-registered aircraft?

Tags: faa-regulations, currency, colombia

I currently hold a Commercial Pilot Certificate issued February,2018. My Flight Review has to be done no later than February 2020.

I have convalidated my FAA License to Colombia. The 90 day currency for carrying passengers applies to both FAA and Colombia.

If I fly Colombian airplanes, does that flight time apply to the 90 day requirement in the U.S.?

In other words, can FAA certificate currency be demonstrated in non-N-registered airplanes?

Answer (score 2):

14 CFR 61.57(a)(ii) details "category, class, and type" but does not mention registration of the aircraft.

Answer (score 1):

FAR 61.57 (a) and (b) both are proficiency based regulations.  The proficiency standard is considered satisfied if you perform the necessary maneuvers (e.g., 3 takeoffs/landings) within a time period of 90 days.  There are also specifications relating to category, class, and type (if applicable) of aircraft and night versus day that apply and are described in the regulation.

Your question asks, for example, if you do 3 touch and go's in a Colombian registered Cessna 172 while in Columbia or the U.S., does that satisfy the related currency requirements specified under FAR 61.57 for operations within the U.S.?

In my opinion, the answer to this is yes.  If you did your 90 day currency in a non "N" registered airplane and used that currency to meet FAR 61.57, what rule would you be in violation of if someone took the position that it was not legal to do this.

I am unable to locate a Legal Interpretation or definitive policy that indicates the currency requirements specified in FAR 61.57 have to be conducted in a "N" registered aircraft to be legal for U.S. operations.

Answer (score 0):

I’d say you would have to ask the Columbian authorities about that. they would be the final arbiters in that case as Columbia is a sovereign nation which operates independently of US laws and regulations.  Unless there is some ICAO standard for pilot currency which both governments honor.

Comment: Why would the Colombian authority be the final arbiters for US laws?

Comment: No they would be the final arbiters over Colombian laws and not US laws.

Comment: OP is asking about currency in the US. He doesn't have an issue with currency in Colombia

Comment: Oh I see - he is talking about operating an airplane registered with the government of Columbia in the United States.  The phrasing he uses to describe that is pretty nebulous.  It sounded more like he wanted to fly airplanes in Columbia.